# Making colorbox pop up on scroll down (inview)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

sorry for the basic question, but I have a page I'm trying to build. It's using inview, which triggers Javascript events on reaching a certain div.

The particular event I want to trigger is a colorbox popup opening. I can see how you make the colorbox open on load, but as I'm a bit new to javascript, I've had difficulty making inview trigger it. I've tried searching, but didn't get anywhere.

I've put it on JSBin. Here's the link: http://jsbin.com/idizop/6/edit

Thanks very much in advance! :)

Comment: can you make inview trigger anything when you want? a basic alert?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, alerts work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
  $('p.inview').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible) 
    { 
      $.colorbox(
        {inline:true, href:"#inline_content"}
      );
    } else {
      $(this).text('nothing');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Not working for me, throwing up lots of warnings. I tried using a random page from my site as the URL. If it helps, the div I tried using as the lightbox content is at the bottom of the html, which popped up fine when triggering it via a link (with '#inline_content' as the URL)

Thanks! :)

Comment: I updated the answer - take a look at the colorbox documentation under "Content Types" for different ways to display content.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much, working perfectly now! :) And I've been having a look, thanks for that :)